# Triggering the set on click listener from options item selected

Tags: java, android

I want to trigger set on click listener from options item selected...

this is my on Options item selected code

```
//cancel event added here
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // ClipData.Item menu_cancel_event=(ClipData.Item)  findViewById(R.id.menu_cancel_event);
        // int Id = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_cancel_event:
                eventMO.setIsDelete(1);
                del();
                return true;
    }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void del() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final long Id = eventMO.getEventId();
        db.delete("event", "Event_ID" + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(Id)});
        db.close();
    }
```

this is my set on click listener

```
btn_create_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_button);
 btn_create_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Instantiate Progress Dialog object
                prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(OccasionActivity.this);
                // Set Progress Dialog Text
                prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                // Set Cancelable as False
                prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

                prgDialog.show();
                UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
                eventMO.setText(custom_Text.getText().toString());
                eventMO.setPlace(event_Place.getText().toString());
                eventMO.setEndTime(end_Time);
                eventMO.setStartTime(start_Time);

                try {
                    //date and time format changed here
                    String eventDate = btn_Date.getText().toString();
                    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
                    Date date1 = date.parse(eventDate);
                    DateFormat convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                    eventDate = convertDate.format(date1);
                    eventMO.setEventDate(eventDate);

                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //eventMO.setEventDate(btn_Date.getText().toString());

                eventMO.setRingeeUserId(userMO.getRingeeUserId());
                //event update functionality added here


                final Long hidden_Text2 = eventId2;
                if ((eventMO.getText() != null) && (eventMO.getPlace() != null) && (eventMO.getEventDate() != null)) {
                    if (hidden_Text2 != null) {
                        eventMO.setEventId(hidden_Text2);
                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            @Override
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return eventDelegates.updateEvent(eventMO, context);
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(String arg0) {
                                prgDialog.dismiss();
                                Intent contactAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserDashBoardActivity.class);
                                // Clears History of Activity
                                contactAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(contactAct);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I want to trigger the set on click listener from on options item selected.....how to call this...please help me to find

My Code

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_occasion, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //cancel event added here
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // ClipData.Item menu_cancel_event=(ClipData.Item)  findViewById(R.id.menu_cancel_event);
        // int Id = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_cancel_event:
                eventMO.setIsDelete(1);
                del();

                //doOnCLickAndOnOptionSelected();
                return true;
    }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void del() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final long Id = eventMO.getEventId();
        db.delete("event", "Event_ID" + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(Id)});
        db.close();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_occasion);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        seekBar_startTime = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        textView_startTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        seekBar_endTime = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
        textView_endTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        btn_Date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.event_date_button);
        event_Place = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Enter_Place);
        custom_Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Custom_Text);
        btn_create_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_button);
        //menu_cancel_event=(button) findViewId(R.id.menu_cancel_event);

        /*box1=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box1);
        box2=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box2);
        box3=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box3);*/
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        btn_Date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Occasion Date");

            }
        });

        seekBar_startTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                start_Time = String.valueOf(progresValue);
                textView_startTime.setText("Event Start Time :" + progresValue);
            }
        });

        seekBar_endTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                end_Time = String.valueOf(progresValue);
                textView_endTime.setText("Event End Time :" + progresValue);
            }
        });

        //eventid get from OccasionFragment here
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {

            Long eventId1 = bundle.getLong("EventID");
            eventId2 = eventId1;
            String eventName = bundle.getString("EventName");
            custom_Text.setText(eventName);
            String eventPlace = bundle.getString("EventPlace");
            event_Place.setText(eventPlace);
            String eventDate = bundle.getString("EventDate");
            try {
                //String eventDate = bundle.getString("EventDate");
                //time string removed from date here
                String result = eventDate.split(" ")[0];
                DateFormat sourceDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                // parse the date string into Date object
                Date date = sourceDate.parse(result);
                DateFormat convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
                // format the date into another format
                result = convertDate.format(date);
                btn_Date.setText(result);


            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Event Start Time and Event End Time string added before the time here
            String eventStart = bundle.getString("EventStart");
            textView_startTime.setText("Event Start Time :" + eventStart);
            String eventEnd = bundle.getString("EventEnd");
            textView_endTime.setText("Event End Time :" + eventEnd);

        }

        btn_create_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Instantiate Progress Dialog object
                 //doOnCLickAndOnOptionSelected();
                    // code

                    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(OccasionActivity.this);
                    // Set Progress Dialog Text
                    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                    // Set Cancelable as False
                    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

                    prgDialog.show();
                    UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
                    eventMO.setText(custom_Text.getText().toString());
                    eventMO.setPlace(event_Place.getText().toString());
                    eventMO.setEndTime(end_Time);
                    eventMO.setStartTime(start_Time);

                try {
                    //date and time format changed here
                    String eventDate = btn_Date.getText().toString();
                    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
                    Date date1 = date.parse(eventDate);
                    DateFormat convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                    eventDate = convertDate.format(date1);
                    eventMO.setEventDate(eventDate);

                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //eventMO.setEventDate(btn_Date.getText().toString());

                eventMO.setRingeeUserId(userMO.getRingeeUserId());
                //event update functionality added here


                final Long hidden_Text2 = eventId2;
                if ((eventMO.getText() != null) && (eventMO.getPlace() != null) && (eventMO.getEventDate() != null)) {
                    if (hidden_Text2 != null) {
                        eventMO.setEventId(hidden_Text2);
                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            @Override
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return eventDelegates.updateEvent(eventMO, context);
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(String arg0) {
                                prgDialog.dismiss();
                                Intent contactAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserDashBoardActivity.class);
                                // Clears History of Activity
                                contactAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(contactAct);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {

                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            @Override
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return eventDelegates.addEvent(eventMO, context);
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(String eventId) {
                                prgDialog.dismiss();
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("eventId", eventId);
                                editor.commit();
                                Intent contactAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactActivity.class);
                                // Clears History of Activity
                                contactAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(contactAct);
                            }
                        }.execute(null, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                } else {
                    prgDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please check Event custom text or Event place or Event date field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });

    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            Date = new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append(" ").toString();
            btn_Date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year).append(" ").toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just extract a method with the body of the `onClickListener` and call that from both places?

Comment: I can't get you...please explain me

Answer (score 2):

In general one does not call android listener callbacks programmatically. That will lead to all kinds of confusion later.

So if you have code you want to run in two listener callbacks you create a method within the same scope as both callbacks (the Activity or Fragment). And then in your call backs you call that method.

Example for *Activity*:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private void doOnCLickAndOnOptionSelected() {
       // code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(...) {

        ...

        btn_create_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_button);
        btn_create_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doOnCLickAndOnOptionSelected();
            }
        }

        ...

        someMenu.setOnOpttionsItemSelectedListener(new OnOpttionsItemSelectedListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // ClipData.Item menu_cancel_event=(ClipData.Item)  findViewById(R.id.menu_cancel_event);
                // int Id = item.getItemId();
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu_cancel_event:
                    eventMO.setIsDelete(1);
                    del();
                    doOnCLickAndOnOptionSelected();
                    return true; 
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where i need to create private void doOnCLickAndOnOptionSelected() {
   // code
}        because On click listener in oncreate method......on options item selected is in on options create menu method

Comment: I updated my answer a bit. But I think you should show us more details of how and where the listeners are set.

Comment: i added my whole activity code in Question(i edited that) from My Code

Comment: @Sathya Try to implement it right next to `private void del() {`

Comment: i tried next to del() method..it shows an error in saved Instance State(on create method) and Date picker fragment

Comment: Thank you Sascha Kolberg